# No JAAS configuration section named 'Server' was found in 'D:\kafka\config\kafka_server_jaas.conf

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, jaas

I am trying to configure Apache Kafka broker for OAuth on a windows 11 laptop. I have downloaded and installed Apache Kafka broker (kafka_2.12-3.4.0) and I am able to run Zookeeper and the broker without any issues. However, I see the following exception after I make changes to a few configuration files based on the documentation available in the internet. I made these changes for OAuth based on Okta identity platform. Following is the error message that I am getting on starting the Zookeeper. I tried this in three different laptops with windows 11, but I get the same error. I have installed kafka in D:\kafka. I didn't find any explanation of this issue anywhere in the internet. I have ensured that the file kafka_server_jaas.conf is under D:\kafka\config but for some reason zookeeper is not able to read the content and identify "Server" section.

> java.io.IOException: No JAAS configuration section named 'Server' was
> found in 'D:\kafka\config\kafka_server_jaas.conf -DOAUTH_WITH_SSL=true
> -DOAUTH_LOGIN_SERVER=https://dev-75552798-admin.okta.com -DOAUTH_LOGIN_ENDPOINT=/oauth2/default/v1/token -DOAUTH_LOGIN_GRANT_TYPE=client_credentials -DOAUTH_LOGIN_SCOPE=kafka -DOAUTH_INTROSPECT_SERVER=https://dev-75552798-admin.okta.com -DOAUTH_INTROSPECT_ENDPOINT=/oauth2/default/v1/introspect -DOAUTH_AUTHORIZATION=Basic somecode
> -DOAUTH_INTROSPECT_AUTHORIZATION=Basic somecode'.

I am providing the contents of the different configuration files below

**server.properties**

```
broker.id=0


num.network.threads=3

num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600

log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

 

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

log.retention.hours=168
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

 

############################# Zookeeper #############################
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper

zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=18000

 

 

############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################


group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

 

##########SECURITY using OAUTHBEARER authentication ###############

sasl.enabled.mechanisms=OAUTHBEARER

sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=OAUTHBEARER

security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT

listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092

#Authorizer for ACL

authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer

super.users=User:0oa9dk17jzUms6BS85d8;

#listener.name.sasl_ssl.oauthbearer.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required unsecuredLoginStringClaim_sub="admin";

################ OAuth Classes #####################

org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required OAUTH_LOGIN_SERVER='https://dev-7555279-admin.okta.com' OAUTH_LOGIN_ENDPOINT='/oauth2/default/v1/token' OAUTH_LOGIN_GRANT_TYPE=client_credentials OAUTH_LOGIN_SCOPE=kafka OAUTH_AUTHORIZATION='Basic somecode' OAUTH_INTROSPECT_SERVER='https://dev-75552798-admin.okta.com' OAUTH_INTROSPECT_ENDPOINT='/oauth2/default/v1/introspect' OAUTH_INTROSPECT_AUTHORIZATION='Basic somecode';
listener.name.sasl_ssl.oauthbearer.sasl.server.callback.handler.class=com.oauth2.security.oauthbearer.OAuthAuthenticateLoginCallbackHandler

listener.name.sasl_ssl.oauthbearer.sasl.server.callback.handler.class=com.oauth2.security.oauthbearer.OAuthAuthenticateValidatorCallbackHandler
```

**zookeeper.properties**

```
dataDir=d:\kafka\zookeeper-data
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=0
# Disable the adminserver by default to avoid port conflicts.
# Set the port to something non-conflicting if choosing to enable this
admin.enableServer=false
# admin.serverPort=8080
```

**kafka_server_jaaas.conf**

```
KafkaServer {

org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required

LoginStringClaim_sub=0oa9dk17jzUms6BS85d8;

debug=true;

};

Server {

org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required

user_super="zookeeper"

user_admin="admin-secret";

debug=true;

};

Client {

org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.DigestLoginModule required

username="admin"

password="admin-secret";

debug=true;

};
```

set the KAFKA_OPTS in the **kafka-run.class.bat** file

```
IF ["%KAFKA_OPTS%"] EQU [""] (

set KAFKA_OPTS="-Djava.security.auth.login.config=D:\kafka\config\kafka_server_jaas.conf -DOAUTH_WITH_SSL=true -DOAUTH_LOGIN_SERVER=https://dev-75552798-admin.okta.com -DOAUTH_LOGIN_ENDPOINT=/oauth2/default/v1/token -DOAUTH_LOGIN_GRANT_TYPE=client_credentials -DOAUTH_LOGIN_SCOPE=kafka -DOAUTH_INTROSPECT_SERVER=https://dev-75552798-admin.okta.com -DOAUTH_INTROSPECT_ENDPOINT=/oauth2/default/v1/introspect -DOAUTH_AUTHORIZATION=Basic somecode -DOAUTH_INTROSPECT_AUTHORIZATION=Basic somecode"

)
```